# Not counting down time correctly

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

I am creating a countdown website. I want it to count down from the current time the my celebration date `2019-11-29 00:00:00`. I want the timezone to be in Australia Brisbane time zone. However, it seems to be that it keeps calculating the amount of time left till my celebration date wrong. Could someone tell me what I did wrong? And once the time hits 0, how can I get rid of the countdown and replace it with `<a href="party.html">Its celebration time</a>`

```js
function dateDiff(a, b) {
    // Some utility functions:
    const getSecs = dt => (dt.getHours() * 24 + dt.getMinutes()) * 60 + dt.getSeconds();
    const getMonths = dt => dt.getFullYear() * 12 + dt.getMonth();

    // 0. Convert to new date objects to avoid side effects
    a = new Date(a);
    b = new Date(b);
    if (a > b) [a, b] = [b, a]; // Swap into order 
    
    // 1. Get difference in number of seconds during the day:
    let diff = getSecs(b) - getSecs(a);
    if (diff < 0) {
        b.setDate(b.getDate()-1); // go back one day
        diff += 24*60*60; // compensate with the equivalent of one day
    }
    // 2. Get difference in number of days of the month
    let days = b.getDate() - a.getDate();
    if (days < 0) {
        b.setDate(0); // go back to (last day of) previous month
        days += b.getDate(); // compensate with the equivalent of one month
    }
    // 3. Get difference in number of months
    const months = getMonths(b) - getMonths(a); 
    return {
        years: Math.floor(months/12),
        months: months % 12,
        days, 
        hours: Math.floor(diff/3600),
        minutes: Math.floor(diff/60) % 24,
        seconds: diff % 60
    };
}

// Date to start on
var celebrationDate = new Date("2019-11-29 00:00:00").toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Brisbane"});

// Update the count every 1 second
!function refresh () {
    const diff = dateDiff(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Brisbane"}), celebrationDate);
    document.getElementById("day-val").innerHTML = diff[Object.keys(diff)[2]];
    document.getElementById("hour-val").innerHTML = diff[Object.keys(diff)[3]];
    document.getElementById("min-val").innerHTML = diff[Object.keys(diff)[4]];
    document.getElementById("sec-val").innerHTML = diff[Object.keys(diff)[5]];
    setTimeout(refresh, 1000)
}()
```

```html
<div id="day-val"></div><div>Days</div><br>
<div id="hour-val"></div><div>Hours</div><br>
<div id="min-val"></div><div>Minutes</div><br>
<div id="sec-val"></div><div>Seconds</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with plain javascript:

1. Get the clients time zone offset
2. Calculate the diff between `client offset` and `"Australian/Brisbane" offset`
3. Calculate time left by `targetDate - currentDate - offsetDiff`
4. Format the result to display it

Example:

```
const minToMS = min => min * 60 * 1000

const getCountDownFromMS = diff => {
    const milliseconds = diff % 1000
    diff = (diff - milliseconds) / 1000
    const seconds = diff % 60
    diff = (diff - seconds) / 60
    const minutes = diff % 60
    diff = (diff - minutes) / 60
    const hours = diff % 24
    diff = (diff - hours) / 24
    const days = diff
    return {
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
        milliseconds
    }
}

const targetDate = new Date('2019-11-29 00:00:00')
// Getting offset with getTimezoneOffset is not reliable, using a database to get time zone offset is needed, like IANA Time Zone Database.
// moment.js internally uses IANA db 
const tzOffset = targetDate.getTimezoneOffset() // Client browsers timezone offset in minutes
const target_tzOffset = -600 // Australia Brisbane timezone offset in minutes
const offset = minToMS(tzOffset - target_tzOffset)
const msLeft = targetDate - new Date() - offset
const result = getCountDownFromMS(msLeft)
```

You should also check [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) as it has many useful features.

Example with moment.js:

```
const now = moment()
const target = moment.tz('2019-11-29 00:00:00', 'Australia/Brisbane')
const result = moment.duration(target.diff(now))
```

Comment: Yes, everything/all times are in Australia brisbane time

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you are using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

What you can do is use the `diff` and `duration` functions like so:

```
const now = moment();
const celebrationDate= moment("2019-11-30 00:00:00");

// this will get the difference between now and celebrationDate
const celebrationDateDiff = expiration.diff(now);

// convert it into duration
const duration = moment.duration(celebrationDateDiff);
```

You can then access the countdown like:

```
duration.days() // will return the number of days
duration.hours() // will return the number of remaining  hours
duration.minutes() // will return the number of remaining minutes
```

Comment: Never used moment.js before. Can you show me a live example? I'm kind of new to javascript

Comment: moment.js is a well-known and reliable javascript library which is a real life saver. Javascripts timezone support is very limited and moment.js solves all problems for you, see this article:
https://medium.com/@toastui/handling-time-zone-in-javascript-547e67aa842d